# search and sort list of objects

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I already filtered a group of object against a specific string entered in the `EditText` and now I need to sort that list with the position of the specified string, how can I do that?

I am already done this

Filter Function

```
public void setFilter(String query) {
    visibleList = new ArrayList<>();
    query = query.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    for (AccountProfile accountProfile : accountProfileList) {
        if (accountProfile.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                .contains(query))
            visibleList.add(accountProfile);
    }

    Collections.sort(visibleList, new AccountNameComparator());


}
```

AccountNameComparator

```
public class AccountNameComparator implements Comparator<AccountProfile> {
@Override
public int compare(AccountProfile first, AccountProfile second) {
    return first.getName().compareTo(second.getName());
}
```

}

the list is sorted but it is based on the `getname()` I need to sort the list with specific substring of the `getname()`

Comment: Just change the compare method to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `sort that list with the position of the specified string`, you could try something like this:

```
public class AccountNameComparator implements Comparator<AccountProfile> {
    private final String query;
    public AccountNameComparator(String query) {
    this.query = query;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(AccountProfile first, AccountProfile second) {
        Integer f = first.getName().indexOf(this.query);
        Integer s = second.getName().indexOf(this.query);
        return f.compareTo(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: String firstName = first.getName().toLowerCase();
String secoundName = second.getName().toLowerCase(); small change , it's worked for me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is slight change in above answer: like below

```
public class AccountNameComparator implements Comparator<AccountProfile> {
private final String query;

public AccoluntNameSortComparator(String query) {
    this.query = query;
}

@Override
public int compare(AccountProfile first, AccountProfile second) {
    String firstName = first.getName().toLowerCase();
    String secoundName = second.getName().toLowerCase();
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    Integer f = firstName.indexOf(query);
    Integer s = secoundName.indexOf(query);
    return f.compareTo(s);
}
}
```